# Send email with file using Nodemailer and Express

Tags: express, multer, nodemailer

I am sending a help request mail using html form and nodemailer
I need to join a file to this email.
I added an input with type file to my html form.
Is it necessary to upload the file (using multer) before sending it with nodemailer ?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used multer with expres and nodemailer attachements. Everything works fine.